# Creating Xaml control in (aspx)web application

Tags: asp.net, ajax, silverlight, xaml

Is it possible to create a .xaml (silverlight) control in a web application project?

I have an aspx application wherein I am using ajax controls and updatepanel. I want to create some silverlight controls in the same project, and load it along with my other pages/controls.

I am not sure if it is possible to create a silverlight control without having a dedicated silverlight project template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question is the same as one of mine: [Is there a way to insert Silverlight XAML into my page using ASP.NET code-behind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023711/is-there-a-way-to-insert-silverlight-xaml-into-my-page-using-asp-net-code-behind)

If so, the answer is basically "not in any sane way, but you can hack it by setting up different parameters (as in weiqure's answer) and using them to dynamically generate the XAML."

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating several controls you might try creating *one* control that dynamically creates it's own content.
You can tell the control what to do by passing initialization parameters to it. [Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189004(VS.95).aspx) the MSDN tutorial and [here's a blog post about it](http://jesseliberty.com/2008/12/26/passing-parameters-into-silverlight-applications/).

I think this approach is no worse than creating controls dynamically. You can probably send it XAML markup (I'm not sure if I remember that correctly, though), otherwise you could path something like "myButton=Type:System.Windows.Controls.Button;Content=Click me!" and then use reflection.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but you can have a solution file that contains your web app and a Silverlight control. Then, to include the control in your web app, add it via the "Silverlight Applications" tab in the web app's project configuration. This will auto-update the .xap file in the web app's ClientBin folder.

Alternatively, you can create the Silverlight control in its own project/solution outside of the web app solution. Then you just need to copy in the .xap file to the web app's ClientBin and add it to your aspx page the usual way. I've found this approach useful when I want to deploy the same control to multiple web sites/projects.